How to run function B after function A when user leaves screen after function A is executed?
I run below 2 lines in order when user clicks button A in flutter.
await ref.read(cognitionRepo).saveMathQuiz(mathModel);
await ref.read(cognitionRepo).saveMultipleChoiceQuiz(multipleChoicesModel);

But I found that in case of that saveMathQuiz is executed but user leaves screen, saveMultipleChoiceQuiz is not executed due to app life cycle.
I want to make sure that saveMultipleChoiceQuiz should be executed once saveMathQuiz is executed even user leaves screen.
ChatGPT suggests to change code like below:
 ref.read(cognitionRepo).saveMathQuiz(mathModel).then((_) {
      return ref
          .read(cognitionRepo)
          .saveMultipleChoiceQuiz(multipleChoicesModel);
    });

But I'm not sure this is ensured to execute saveMultipleChoiceQuiz.
Is there any solution in this case?
Is ChatGPT's solution reasonable?
